# Unable to display image with dynamic path using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and i am using nextjs framework,Right now i am trying to fetch image data from database using axios,I am using loop for fetch image,Image in database is
like "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/upload/blog/1669111567istockphoto-1354441996-170667a.jpg" means
i am getting full path of image,But whenever i am trying to fetch data then i am getting following
error

```
Error: Invalid src prop ...on `next/image`, hostname "diggdevelopment.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
```

Also i want if array(todoList) is not empty then loop should work(add condition if array not empty) and want to show number of records ( like 1 2 3 etc..)
I tried with following code

```
{post.map(todoList => (
    <td><Image src={todoList.image} width={5}
    height={50}/> </td>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `next.config.js` file and put your domain where images are stored like below:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  presets: ["next/babel"],
  images: {
    domains: [
      "diggdevelopment.com",
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

You can check if post is empty or not using below codes:

```
{post.length > 0 ? (
  post.map((todoList, index) => (
    <td key={index+1}>
      <Image src={todoList.image} width={5} height={50} />
    </td>
  ))
) : (
  <p>No data</p>
)}
```

index will give you numeric value from 0 to the length of the array

Comment: can you tell me how to add condition if todoList is not empty ? means loop should work if array(todoList is not empty)

Comment: Update your questions for this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i dont want "id" , i want serial number ( like 1 , 2 , 3), Hope you understand

Comment: Check updated again.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the `loader` function

This will generate the URLs for your image. It appends a root domain to your provided src

```
<td><Image loader={() => todoList.image} src={todoList.image} width={5}
```

Comment: @Sachin Ranawaka sir, can you tell me how to add condition if todoList is not empty ? means loop should work if array(todoList is not empty)

Comment: `todoList?.image || 'other_url'`

Comment: sir i am new in nextjs so can you please write full code and autoincrement number ( like i++) so i can print number with <td>